# Closing modal shifts body up and breaks scroll in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, google-chrome, zurb-foundation

This started occurring in chrome when I updated to Chrome 55 from 53. I'm using WordPress with Foundation and opening the media manager to add a file while on a form. I don't add any files, just close the window. Once I've closed the modal the page jumps down to the footer and then I can only scroll up about halfway (hides the top 1700px if that makes a difference) before the scrollbar stops and I can't get any further up. I can go into inspect and add 1700px padding to the top and see all the content again. It also adds a bunch of white space below the footer that wasn't there before the modal opened so it looks like it's keeping the scrollbar the same size but just shifting everything up.

A few CSS settings I have:

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

I've also tried modifying the 'open-modal' class on the body with no luck

```
body.open-modal {
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
}
```

I've looked through everything and have no fixed elements in the body except the navbar. This is not occurring on either Firefox 50 or IE 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a perfect fix but it seems to be working. I found [this answer](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/38019#comment_29784) on the Foundation forums and then changed my CSS to this:

```
body.modal-open {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Now when the modal is open there is still a ton of white space that appears below my content but the scrollbar gets longer so I can scroll up to the top. Closing the modal now jumps me back to where I clicked open the modal and restores the scrollbar to normal. It seems to be an issue with Foundation 5.